# How to send only one email when error occurs in aspx.net

Tags: asp.net, email

So I have an aspx application that generates an error when the database goes down. I would like the application to send one and only one error when this occurs. Otherwise if multiple users hit the application I could get tons of emails, especially because the page refreshes.

I don’t want to use a database because that may be the reason for the error. I tried using a session variable, but it didn’t work. Any ideas?

My session variable code:

```
'We only want to send out this email if we it has not yet been sent this session
    If Session("AlreadySentStaleDBemail") Is Nothing Then
        SendEmailToTeam("The Results Database has not inserted any entries in over 60 minutes.")
        Session("AlreadySentStaleDBemail") = "email sent already"
    End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using an application variable:

```
 Application("AlreadySentStaleDBemail")
```

Comment: That will work on the web server with that instance of the application.

Comment: @DOK - If you mean on a Web Farm Application variables are per machine then yes, another way will need to be implemented.   Or maybe an Application variable is "good enough".

Comment: We have two web servers, so if each sent an email for two total that would be fine. I will give this a try. - Thanks